# Sencha Touch 2: Add tabs to a form panel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to add the following tabs to the following panel, between the top and bottom toolbars on the panel. Is this possible and could you please provide an example for how these two files would be combined?

Thanks for your help!

Panel:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    id: 'productCard',

    config: {
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: false,
        centered: true,
        height: '95%',
        width: '98%',
        items: [
            {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                title: '',
                id: 'productTitle'
            },
            {
                docked: 'bottom',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Close',
                        ui: 'back',
                        id: 'closeProductCard'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Tabs

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Tabs', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.field.Toggle'
    ],

    config: {
        activeItem: 0,
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'top',
            autoScroll: 'auto',
            ui: 'neutral',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Tab 1',
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        defaults: {
                            labelWidth: '35%',
                            labelAlign: 'top'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'togglefield',
                                name: 'toggle',
                                label: 'Toggle'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'Tab 2',
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset',
                        defaults: {
                            labelWidth: '35%',
                            labelAlign: 'top'
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'togglefield',
                                name: 'toggle',
                                label: 'Toggle'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ext.define('Myapp.view.Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
    'Ext.field.Toggle'
    ],

    config: {
        activeItem: 0,
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'top',
            autoScroll: 'auto',
            ui: 'neutral',
            layout: {
                pack: 'center'
            }
        },
        items: [{
            xtype:'toolbar',
            docked:'top'
        }, {
            docked: 'bottom',
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [
            {
                text: 'Close',
                ui: 'back',
                id: 'closeProductCard'
            }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Tab 1',
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                defaults: {
                    labelWidth: '35%',
                    labelAlign: 'top'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'togglefield',
                    name: 'toggle',
                    label: 'Toggle'
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        },{
            title: 'Tab 2',
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                defaults: {
                    labelWidth: '35%',
                    labelAlign: 'top'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'togglefield',
                    name: 'toggle',
                    label: 'Toggle'
                }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
});
```

Ok I merged the two views into the product view. This will display the tabs panel with toolbars on top and bottom. Hopefully this still works with the dynamics of it being a details page

Comment: That worked! However, the toggle fields on each tab are not showing up. Is there an additional step to add the content of each tab to the panel? Thanks for your help

Comment: I see that could be an issue. Why not combine the two views together, by adding toolbars to the tabs view.

Comment: I've tried merging the tabs into the Products view, but have not gotten that to work correctly (the tabs do not show up). Ultimately I would like the Products view to be a details page, where depending on the preceding list selection, it shows product info organized into tabs. I have the list selection working to open the Products view, but am stuck at this point. Please let me know if this seems like a viable approach, or I am way off base. Thanks for your help!